# Cumulative/Rolling Exponential Moving Average

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How do I compute a rolling/cumulative exponential moving average. I get an error stating the ewm function doesn't support expanding data frames.

```py
df.expanding(1)['value'].mean() # works
df.expanding(1)['value'].ewm(halflife=.05) # fails
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `df.ewm(halflife=0.5)['value'].mean()` is what you are looking for.
More infos [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html)